# Passing form validation error using codeigniter and jquery ui pop up dialog box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

just want to ask a question how can I pass a codeigniter form validation in a popup dialog box. Right now i created a form which contains the list of the category together with Edit and Delete button. The scenario is when a member clicked the update button it will popup a dialog box displaying an Add New Category form. Actually i loaded my html form inside the popup. My problem is if the user entered a duplicate category name a form validation should appear inside the popup dialog. In my case it will open a new page displaying my form together the validation error. How can i display the form validation in my popup jquery? That's all guys thanks.

Here's a bit of my code (im using Codeigniter)

***//homepage.php (display the list of category details)***

```
   <?php $data_var = array('name'=>'category','id'=>'addForm'); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('category_controller/delete_category',$data_var); ?>
   <input class="classname1"  type="button" value="ADD" name="add_category"/> <!-- button for add -->
       <!-- BLOW IS MY FOREACH FOR DISPLAYING INFO -->
        .
        .
        .  

                           foreach($queryViewEntries as $row){

                                $temp_id = $row['salescatid'];

                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td width='5%' style='text-align: center'><input type='checkbox' name='category[]' value=".$row['salescatid']." id=check".$row['salescatid']." onclick='check(this)' /></td>";
                                    echo "<td width='10%'>{$row['salescatname']}</td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$row['salescatdesc']}</td>";
                                    ?>
                                        <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <?php
                                                $cat_id = $row['salescatid'];
                                            ?>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>" />
                                            <input type="button" name="edit_item" data-value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>" value="EDIT" />
                                            <input type="button" name="delete_item" value="DELETE" data-value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>" />
                                        </td>
                                <?php
                                echo "</tr>";

                            } 
....
<!-- MY DIV -->
<div id="popup" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="edit" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="delete" style="display: none;"></div>
....
....
<!-- BELOW IS MY JQUERY FUNCTION THAT WILL CALL THE POP UP AND LOAD MY HTML FORM INSIDE IT.

  $(function(){

    /* FOR ADD PAGE */    
    $(".hero-unit input[name=add_category]").on('click',function(){
        $('#popup').load("<?php echo site_url("category_controller/addCategoryItem/"); ?>").dialog({
            title: "Add New Category",
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 450,
            modal:true,
            open: function (event, ui) { window.setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery(document).unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay').unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay'); }, 100);
            },
            close: function() {
                $('#popup').dialog("close");
            }
        });
    });
```

**//category_controller.php(my controller)**

```
<?php
   class Category_Controller extends CI_Controller{

      public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
      }

      public function addCategoryItem(){
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Category Name','required|is_unique[sales_category.salescatname]');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
         if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
             $data['title'] = "Add Item";
             $data['copyright'] = date('Y');
             $this->load->view('User/header/header_user',$data);
             $this->load->view('Item/contents/addNewItem');
         }else{
             $this->category_model->addCategory();
             $this->load->view('Item/contents/duccessAdd');   
         }
      }

   }
```

**//controller_model.php(my model function)**

```
 public function addCategory(){

        $cname = ucwords($this->input->post('name'));
        $cdesc = $this->input->post('description');

        $insertCategory = array(
            'salescatid' => NULL,
            'salescatname' => $cname,
            'salescatdesc' => $cdesc,
        );
        $result = $this->db->insert('sales_category',$insertCategory);

        if($result){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
```

**//addNewItem.php(my form for adding new category)**

```
 <?php $attr = array('class'=>'form-signin','id'=>'addForm'); ?>
  <?php echo form_open('category_controller/insertItem',$attr); ?>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading"></h2>
        <h5 style="font-weight: normal;">Category Name:</h5>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Category Name" required="required" name="name" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"/>
            <label style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></label>
        <h5 style="font-weight: normal;">Desciption</h5>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Description" required="required" name="description" value="<?php echo set_value('description'); ?>" />
            <label style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error('description'); ?></label>
        <br />
        <div align="right">
            <input type="submit" value="OK" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" value="CANCEL" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name='cancel' />
        </div>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

That's a sample of my code I hope you can help me guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices, both requiring the use of javascript. The first is to perform the form validation in javascript directly provided you don't need to do any complex form checking which requires information from the server/database. Alternatively you can submit the form using ajax and read the request to either display the errors or provide the user with a success message.

Since it looks like you are checking to see if a category already exists in the database you will <del>probably</del> need to use ajax to perform the validation.

This code will stop the form from submitting normally and call a javascript function instead.

```
<?php $attr = array('class'=>'form-signin','id'=>'addForm', 'onsubmit'=>'submitForm(); return false;'); ?>
  <?php echo form_open('category_controller/insertItem',$attr); ?>
```

Then somewhere on your page in javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
    url:<?php echo site_url('category_controller/insertItem'); ?>,
    data: {field1:$("#field1").val(), field2:$("#field2").val()}
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#someDiv').innerHTML(data);
    };

    return FALSE;
}
```

(You will need to list each piece of POST data you want to send to the server and retrieve its value in the `data` section.)

Your `addCategoryItem()` function in your controller being called by the ajax should return only either a success message, or the validation errors. When the request completes whatever that page outputs will be put inside of the element with id `someDiv`.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. I will try that. I really don't have an idea how to do this. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2585508 Take a look at [the W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) ajax tutorial if you need some more background on how ajax works and the ideas behind it.

Comment: Thank you, i really have enough knowledge in using ajax. So i need to study it now. Thanks guys for the help.